# Shimano st-ef-29-8 With hydraulic brakes - Can Integrated Brake Levers with Shifters be Separated?

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I have an older Trek mountain bike that has front and rear disc brakes.  I have newer Shimano brake calipers and levers that I want to use but on the old setup the brake lever is integrated with the shifter.  Has anyone ever disconnected the brake lever?  It looks like a pin is pressed in and holds the lever.
[image: lever viewed from underneath]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually got these shifters on the old bike at work. I think it might be possible to remove the brake lever, but the housing is going to get in the way of fitting new levers where you want them. I'll try to have a look later - easy as the plastic lid is broken and missing on one.

On similar brakes, the pin isn't pressed in, and can come out of the top with the lid off and the cable removed. That would be non-destructive and worth a try.

In this case it looks like the pin is larger underneath than on top, so driving it out from the top might be worth a try. However by feel, and by expectation given gravity, I would expect something to stop it coming out by itself.  It's possible the return spring also retains the pin; it's also possible there's a circlip in there somewhere.

Comment: The pin does not seem to come out on mine.  I tried pounding on it with a punch but am afraid I will break it.  See pictures I just attached

Comment: I've moved the picture to the question, but added some more thoughts to the answer.  Your edits prompted me to look at it this morning, but I only had a moment.  I keep meaning to swap mine for a slightly different spare that's complete.  Then I'd have one I could dismantle on the bench

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question.  I could not get the pin out so I need up cutting it.